# Macro to change font in email, dependent on which email account is being used

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, fonts, macros, microsoft-outlook-2013

I have several different email account for different companies I work with, and each one has a different corporate font for emails.  Anybody got any ideas how to quickly change this over when switching between accounts in Outlook?  I don't want to have to revert to splitting into different Outlook profiles.

I have no idea where to start - I've researched it many forums and can't find any suggestion.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! More details are needed. Please tell us what you have researched and attempted to resolve this. Take a minute to read **[ask]** to improve your question.

Comment: Well, Outlook allows you to set a default font (stationery), which is usually Calibri 11.  However one company I work with prefers emails to use Trebuchet MS 10 (gray) and another prefers Segoe UI 11.  I want to be able to switch from one to the other in a single click, rather than having to go into the font settings.  Better still, a VBA script or Macro that could do it for me based on what account I had selected

Comment: It is understood what you *want*, but Super User is not a script writing service. We would like to know what you have researched and attempted so far so we can help you overcome where you have gotten stuck.

Comment: I have no idea where to start - I've researched it many forums and can't find any suggestion.  However I've not given up because I can't believe that its never been thought of before or that there isn't _somebody_ out there that's had a go at solving what is really a flaw with Outlook

Comment: Fair enough. I added that comment to your question so readers know you have researched.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I should update this with the closest I have come to an answer so far.....

I have written a macro that changes the font of the *selected* text, and created a shortcut in the toolbar.  Therefore I compose my email in the font I **don't** want to use, then select the entire reply and click the macro.

I can provide the code (which is quite simple) if anybody is interested

Comment: Hello,
Would it be possible to provide me with this macro? :)
I have a similar problem and this macro could help me